# Multiple proxy configurations for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I use VSCode in a company computer (WSL in Windows) for work and at home (Ubuntu).

My problem is that Windows has one network/proxy configuration (it's a global proxy.pac, no password required) but inside WSL I need another proxy configuration (a http://user:pass@localhost:port). Finally, at home I don't need anything.

What's the best way to configure VSCode?

I'm having problem because the proxy config is for all profiles, so, even having different profiles for work/home doesn't work.

Comment: how are you currently doing it?

Comment: @user adding proxy at work, deleting at home, getting pissed when I forget, and stuff doesn't work